# Why is SQL output parameter always null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBaseSixtyTwoString]
    @a_number_to_convert int,
    @v_temp_val nvarchar(256) output
AS

DECLARE @v_modulo INTEGER;    
DECLARE @v_temp_int decimal(38) = @a_number_to_convert;      
DECLARE @v_temp_char VARCHAR(1);      

DECLARE @c_base62_digits VARCHAR(62) = '0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ';   

 IF ( @a_number_to_convert = 0 )  
 BEGIN  
   SET @v_temp_val = '5';    
 END      

 WHILE ( @v_temp_int <> 0 )  
 BEGIN  

   SET @v_modulo = @v_temp_int % 62;    
   SET @v_temp_char = substring( @c_base62_digits, @v_modulo + 1, 1 );    
   SET @v_temp_val = @v_temp_char + @v_temp_val;     
   SET @v_temp_int = floor(@v_temp_int / 62);    

 END
```

I am calling it like this:

```
declare @shorturl nvarchar(256)
exec dbo.GetBaseSixtyTwoString 1, @shorturl output
```

But the variable **@shorturl** always returns null

However if I put print statements in the SP I can see that **@v_temp_val** is indeed getting the correct value.

What am I missing?

Comment: How did you test that `@v_temp_val` is getting the correct value? On the loop's first iteration, if `@v_temp_val` is `NULL`, then `@v_temp_char + @v_temp_val` will always equal `NULL`, because `{anything} + NULL = NULL`.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I tested correct value using print statements. BUT it appears I was testing the wrong variable, v_temp_char and not v_temp_val. Obvious looking at it with fresh eyes today!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialise `@v_temp_val` inside the stored procedure to non-NULL value, to `''`.

If `@v_temp_val` is `NULL`, then this line would still result in `NULL`:

```
SET @v_temp_val = @v_temp_char + @v_temp_val;
```

because "value" + NULL = NULL

Answer (score 3):

check if any value you put into variable @v_temp_val is null. note that any non-null value + NULL will result to NULL:

```
SET @v_temp_val = ISNULL(@v_temp_char, '') + ISNULL(@v_temp_val, '');
```